# Dynamically created Selectmenu options override the selected option with the first value

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi I have dynamically created selectmenu options that populates the drop down correctly. My problem is, on selecting any option(value) from the list of drop down, the value gets overriden with the first value from the list.

Kindly refer this fiddle to understand the problem http://jsfiddle.net/praleedsuvarna/SwLNG/

I had refered to few of the earlier post, but non of them was of much help.

Below is the html code for your reference

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="checkout">
        <div data-id="commonHeader" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#" rel="external" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>
            <h1>Checkout</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <label for="state_o">State:</label>
            <select name="state_o" id="state_o" data-native-menu="false">
            </select>
        </div>
  <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Following is the java script

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#checkout', function(){  
    var stateList = "";
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="Maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>';
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="AP">AP</option>';
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="MP">MP</option>';
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>';
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="Goa">Goa</option>';
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="Karnataka">Karnataka</option>';
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="Gujarat">Gujrat</option>';
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="Assam">Assam</option>';
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="Bihar">Bihar</option>';
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="Haryana">Haryana</option>';
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="J&K">J&K</option>';
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="Kerala">Kerala</option>';
    stateList = stateList + '<option value="Odisha">Odisha</option>';
    $("#state_o").html(stateList);
    $("#state_o").selectmenu("refresh", true);
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: how ! It looks like when you have selected something in your select, the UI automaticly goes back to the previous page, triggering the 'pageShow event'. That's why your list is reseted. EDIT : what does the "refresh" option ? (can't find it in the doc)

Comment: "refresh" option is important to fill the list dynamically. If i remove the "refresh" option then the drop down list will never fill in the first place

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I have edited my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have selected something in your select, the UI automaticly goes back to the previous page, triggering the 'pageShow event'. That's why your list is reseted.

For instance, you can replace you event handler, as you are already in the "onDomReady" part.

replace

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#checkout', function(){
```

by

```
$(function(){
```

Comment: I guess this doesn't work when my page is not an index page. In my case this particular page opens while navigating through a different page. So I have to keep this piece of code under "pageshow" for it to load at the first place. Can you suggest me an alternative option?

Comment: create a `init()` function and a `initialised` variable. On pageshow, if not initialised, initialize with `init()` and set `initialised` to true. Else, nothing...

Comment: Can you please help me out with the exact code? I know i am asking for more, but i am very new to jquery so I am finding it difficult to get it done

Comment: Thanks a ton... it worked for me. I have one more question. Can we create multiple such init functions. If yes, how? Say I have multiple such drop down list and i have to handle all of those in similar fashion, can i do that?

Comment: mwell, if they are all in the same page, just add them to the init function. Copy and adjust the init function in each page

Answer (score 2):

Even though @TCHdvlp's answer is extremely accurate, I feel like using `DOM ready` (or) its equivalent `$(function() {...})` kinda defeats the purpose of having the "page events" which are jQuery Mobile's strengths. The reason is because these jQM events fire much earlier than `dom ready` so using the native jqm events are faster than `ready`.

As far as you question is concerned, **you could achieve this without `ready` by just using `pageinit` instead of `pageshow`**. Pageinit will fire only once so your options wont be reset. More info <kbd>[here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/api/events.html)</kbd>

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function () {
    /*populate select here*/
});
```

<kbd>[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/SwLNG/4/)</kbd>

What I've changed in the demo :

1. Changed `pageshow` to `pageinit`
2. Changed `onDOMReady` option to `wrapInBody` (next to where you select jQuery) - you must always jquery, jquery mobile in `<head/>` and the rest of your JS files in `<body/>`

<kbd>[And here's a better way of appending select](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/SwLNG/5/)</kbd>
What I've changed in this demo :

1. A better way to append `selectmenu` to HTML - this is faster and cleaner